# Convert a d3 line chart to a bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

D3 newbie here. I have a line chart that looks exactly the way I want it.

Here is my code, tweaked a bit, but mostly borrowed from [here](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9a84fa008c5a0e77cd8c2ed7fb7a2a8e). :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="lib/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/d3-dsv/d3-dsv.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/d3-fetch/d3-fetch.min.js"></script>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 70},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.running_total); });


// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("q3.csv").then(function(data) {

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.year = parseTime(d.year);
      d.running_total = +d.running_total;
  });
  console.log("d", data)
  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.running_total; })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
      .data([data])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);

  // Add the x Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // text label for the x axis
  svg.append("text")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," +
                           (height + margin.top + 20) + ")")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Year");

  // Add the y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // text label for the y axis
  svg.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
      .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Running Total");

});

</script>
</body>
```

And the SVG looks like this:
[image]

That is all great. Now I want to add bars to the chart as well with the same data. I tried following the example how the `valueline` were created, but apparently `rect` can't be created the same way. Here is how I tried it:

```
var valuebox = d3.rect()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.running_total); })
    .width(x.bandwidth)
    .height(function(d) { return height - y(d.running_total); });
```

Then just after I append the path, I thought I could append my rect.

```
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("fill-opacity", 0.8)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .join("rect")
      .attr("d", d => valuebox)
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this by adding the following code below where I was adding the line:

```
svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
      .attr("width", (width/data.length - 1))
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.running_total); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.running_total); });
```